# get next index of particular key value

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I've array like this

```
[1] => Array(
            [description] => signer
            [boundingPoly] => Array (
                          [vertices] => Array (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [x] => 399
                                            [y] => 408
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [x] => 557
                                            [y] => 408
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [x] => 557
                                            [y] => 457
                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [x] => 399
                                            [y] => 457
                                        )

                          )
              )
)
[2] => Array (
            [description] => -
            [boundingPoly] => Array (
                          [vertices] => Array (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [x] => 399
                                            [y] => 408
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [x] => 557
                                            [y] => 408
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [x] => 557
                                            [y] => 457
                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [x] => 399
                                            [y] => 457
                                        )

                                )

                        )
)

[3] => Array (
            [description] => 1
            [boundingPoly] => Array (
                          [vertices] => Array (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [x] => 399
                                            [y] => 408
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [x] => 557
                                            [y] => 408
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [x] => 557
                                            [y] => 457
                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [x] => 399
                                            [y] => 457
                                        )

                                )

                        )
)
```

Now first I've searched `signer` keyword with this code

```
if(stripos($eachItem['description'], "signer") !== false){}
```

And then I'm searching values which are in `description` keys.

```
foreach($items as $index => $eachItem) {
   if(stripos($eachItem['description'], "signer") !== false) {
      if($eachItem['description'] == "signer") {
          $current = $eachItem['description'];
                      $keys = array_keys($eachItem);
                      $ordinal = (array_search($current,$keys)+1)%count($keys);
                      $next = $keys[$ordinal];
      }
   }
}
```

now what I want is to get `description` key of each index for example at index 1 the `description` is `signer` and at index 2 `description` is `-` sign and at index 3 `description` is `1` now I want `description` value of each index so when I concatenate the `description` key the value will be like this `signer-1` in my code it get next key which is `boundingPoly` of same index but I want only `description` keys of each index.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get you. Please add your expected array output

Comment: read last paragraph again please.

Comment: Because second `description` key index fail in this if statement `if(stripos($eachItem['description'], "signer") !== false) {..}` That's why your not getting second and third .

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do this. output is like this: `array('singer-1', 'singer-2', ...)`

```
$visited = -1;
$output = [];

foreach($items as $index => $item) {

  if($item['description'] == 'singer')
  {
      $output[$visited+1] = 'singer';
      $visited++;
  }
  else
  {
      $output[$visited] .= $item['description'];
  }

}
```

Comment: I want `description` key of each index I've three index and only `description` keys should be retrieve and when I concatenate my variables the value will be like this `signer-1` and read my updated question again.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure about your expected output. But try this if you want only keys

```
$a = [
    ["description" => "signer"],
    ["description" => "-"],
    ["description" => "1"]
];

//To get all values of description key
$desKeys = array_column($a, 'description'); //output ["singer", "-", "1"]
echo implode('', desKeys ); //output singer-1
```